# Struts bean cannot be found

Tags: struts, struts-1, struts-html

I'm having a problem with Struts. It's not recognizing a bean, even though it's defined one line above

I have this code

```
<logic:iterate id="com" name="Handler" property="commandList">
23:                             <optgroup id="${com.id}" style="display:none;">
24:                                 <logic:iterate id="rem" name="com" property="remotes">
25:                                     <option value="${rem.id}"><bean:write name="rem" property="name"/></option>
26:                                 </logic:iterate>
27:                             </optgroup>
28:                         </logic:iterate>
```

and I get the following error in line 25:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean: "rem" in any scope
```

Which does not make sense, because the bean is defined just above on line 24

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state, the syntax of your code is correct. My guess is that one of the `remotes` bean's object is a null value. In that case, according to [struts1 reference](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#logic%3aiterate) :

> If the collection you are iterating over can contain null values, the
>   loop will still be performed but no page scope attribute (named by the
>   id attribute) will be created for that loop iteration. You can use the
>   `<logic:present>` and `<logic:notPresent>` tags to test for this case.

The `<bean:write name="rem" property="name"/>` tag will be executed, but rem won't exist in any scope. Check for null values in your Array/List/Map/etc `remotes`, or add a test using the `<logic:present>` tag.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. The bean had a null value